# URL User-Agent?

Tags: user-agent

There is a URL and unfortunately I see no content, one optimized PHP file This URL, content to hide with User Agent.

How can I know this URL which User-Agent used ?

Comment: This question does not make sense. Literally, the first sentence is not parseable. Who upvotes this rubbish?

Comment: This complicated question for me, with bad English nor complicated :(

Answer (score 2):

You cannot receive the user-agent information from the URL. You can only retrieve it from the headers through a server-side check.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: ok thanks I have another question, If I know what user agent uses this URL as I can see content ? are there certain code ?